# Advice on Prototype for a Business Intelligence System

Tags: sql-server-2008, prototype, business-intelligence

Our organisation lacks any data mining or analytical tools, so I'm trying to persuade them to implement a Business Intelligence solution using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2. They've asked for a prototype, so they can get a better idea of what Business Intelligence can do for them.

I'm assuming that the prototype will consist of -

- A subset of data from a critical application
- Integration Services (SSIS): Used to clean the data subset?
- Analysis Services (SSAS): Used to create and maintain a dimensional model based on that data subset? Data Mining?
- Reporting Services (SSRS): Used to create, maintain and update a 'dashboard' of reports.

I want to show how a Business Intelligence solution with data mining and analytic capabilities can help their organisation perform better.

As this is the first time I've done this, I'd value advice from other people on whether this prototype is realistic or not. And does anyone know of any easily-accessible real-life examples that I can show them?

Comment: Is SQL Server already licensed?  If not, and cost is a sticking point, there are some decent free BI platforms out there, such as Pentaho and MicroStrategy.  Hopefully you'll demonstrate value and get a budget to upgrade to pro before you outgrow the free version.

Comment: Yes, SQL Server is already licensed. But thanks for suggesting those BI Platforms. I might take a look at them later on.

Answer (score 2):

my thoughts …

- Don’t overestimate the size (in terms of time) of a new DWH project.
- Start with something not very complex and well understood in terms of business rules.

The biggest problem we have had with new DWH projects/pilots (we are a DWH consultancy so have a number of clients) is getting management support of it. Often the DWH will be sponsored by someone in IT and there is no real board level support, so the project takes a long time to progress and it is difficult to get resources for it.

The best projects we have found are ones that have levels of support in three areas: Management (board level), IT and Business (preferably someone with good understanding of the business rules involved).

Have a look at [Ralph Kimball’s Data Warehouse Toolkit](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Data-Warehouse-Toolkit-Complete-Dimensional/dp/0471200247) which goes through different styles of DWH design for different industries. It is **very** good!

The tools I expect you would use (I’ve added a couple of technologies here)

- SSIS (ETL tool) is used to Extract (from source systems) Transform (data into appropriate form the load) and Load (into Dim and Fact tables)
- SSAS (OLAP tool) is used to create/process an OLAP cube. **Warning**: there is quite a large learning curve on this tool!!
- SSRS (reporting tool) is used to create static and dynamic reports/dashboards.
- MS Excel. There are free data mining models that can be added in and when connected to an OLAP cube which will allow very interesting DM to be performed.
- Windows Sharepoint Services (WSS) (comes free with a Windows Server operating systems) to deploy your SSRS reports onto.

This is a good prototype scope in terms of technologies (if you are from the MS background), but the spread of technologies is very large and for one person coming in cold to them, this is perhaps unrealistic.

The most critical thing is to get the DWH star schema design correct (and there will be a number of solutions that are “correct” for any set of data), otherwise your OLAP cube design will be flawed and very difficult to build.

I would get a local DWH consultant to validate your design before you have built it. Make sure you give them a very tight scope of not changing much otherwise most consultants will “tinker” with things to make them “better”.

Good Luck!

Comment: I've already built the prototype using all the tools you've suggested. I presented the prototype to Business stakeholders and got a very positive and enthusiastic response. Unfortunately, IT Management put this project on hold indefinitely. I'm disappointed, as I was hoping to use this prototype to start a career in Business Intelligence. What's your opinion on me showing this prototype to prospective employers as a way to demonstrate my work?

Comment: Well done @Spacehamster on using all the technologies! I'm impressed. Its unfortunate that sometimes parts of the business get caught up in "strategic" or "political" decisions that stall really good projects. The skills you have developed are definitely worthwhile and transferable. I'd be very cautious about showing the prototype to prospective employers, except with the explicit permission of your company, as they paid you to develop it, so the IP (and more importantly the data) is theirs. The market in Tassie is pretty small for DWH/BI, but certainly in Melbourne/Sydney is it very big. GL!

Comment: Marcus, thanks for the encouragement! I'm going to develop a new prototype using dummy data instead. Hopefully it'll demonstrate to prospective employers that I've got what it takes.

Answer (score 1):

It's been 2 years since the question was posted and of course, there has been updates in the world of business Intelligence. We now have couple of great tools for prototyping in the Microsoft Business Intelligence World: 
- Power Query (Self Service ETL) 
- Power Pivot.

Hope this helps someone just getting started w/ building prototypes.

Comment: Yes I would have to agree @Paras_doshi. We are involved in a project using PowerBI (Pivot & Query) to discover and document the business rules of a process, which, once it is signed off, then will form the basis for a more robust Tabular model built in SQL Server. PowerPivot we find starts to become fragile when it is pushed in terms of data volumes and DAX complexities and design choices are quite important in achieving a robust model.